# Whitelisting all IPs or switching to a different hosting platform?

Tags: sql, azure, heroku, static-ip-address

Basically a current node.js app that I'm working on is hosted on Heroku. Since heroku dynos are highly dynamic I can't whitelist the dyno's ip on my Azure SQL Database. Add-ons like Fixie and Proximo would seem like the best solution, but I can't find support or documentation for integrating a proxy with node.js tedious package or node-mssql.

Should I just forget Heroku and switch to a hosting platform like Azure which can give me a dedicated ip or should I just open the SQL database to all ip addresses?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should. And the reason is latency.
As another temporary solution, you can write a proxy on azure side, and whitelist it the proxy on your Azure SQL database. It worths to mention that adding another hop will slow down your response times too.

Comment: Thank you very much!